# Flutter web break points change to unverified when the chrome connects

Tags: flutter, debugging, breakpoints, flutter-web

I had a Flutter project for Android and iOS and the debugging using break points and tracing the code worked fine.
When I added web platform it was Ok at first, but at some point I lost the breakpoints. All of them turn to gray circles (unverified) as soon as the chrome connects and I they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I upload my webapp to a sub-folder on the server, so the base path is not `/` anymore. I change the
`<base href="/">` to `<base href="/pwa/">` in `web/index.html` file for it to work on the server. And this was what caused the confusion between the debugger and chrome.

Changing it back to `<base href="/">` made the break points active again.

Hope it saves someone several days and many builds and new test projects that took me to find the problem.

BTW: Please let me know if there is any option I can set in `launch.json` to fix it so I don't have to change that `href` back and forth.